# Send Firebase FCM HTTP v1 API with Java (SOLVED)

Tags: java, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

at the moment I'm sending messages with a static Server-Key

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", SERVERKEY);
```

Now I will send the messages with an access token via OAuth 2.0.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer ACCESSTOKEN");
```

The access token is valid for 1 hour.
I need to retrieve a new valid access token.
I'm trying to implement this with the Firebase documentation.
A json file was generate in the Firebase console.

```
private static final String MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { MESSAGING_SCOPE };

    private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service.json"))
            .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
        googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();
    AccessToken token = googleCredentials.getAccessToken();

    return token.getTokenValue();
    }
```

But the output after a longer time is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getDone(Ljava/util/concurrent/Future;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.finishRefreshAsync(OAuth2Credentials.java:287)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.access$300(OAuth2Credentials.java:67)
....
```

I have embedded the firebase-admin lib as maven project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!

The above error is in Eclipse IDE.

Under IntelliJ the error output is another:

```
Error getting access token for service account: Connect timed out
```

The proxy settings in the IntelliJ IDE have no change, but in the source code:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "PROXYSERVER");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "PROXYPORT");
System.setProperty("com.google.api.client.should_use_proxy","true");
```

I receive an access token.